# Por que no me da un resultado en FLOAT

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo este query que deberia sumar todos los numeros cuando una columna es llamada "T2"y dividirlo por el
total de llamadas, siendo los dos enteros, deberia darme un resultado Decimal pero sigue arrojando un entero.

```
Select
CAST(
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN tier = 't2' 
            THEN 
                CAST(total_calls AS FLOAT) 
            ELSE 0.00 
        END
    ) 
AS FLOAT) 
/ 
SUM(
    CAST(total_calls AS FLOAT)
    )
From #prueba_real
```

mi tabla #prueba_real tiene los 10 datos INT diferentes en total_calls y tiene datos Varchr en tier (t1,t2) pero me da error y no me da el resultado en decimales de dos numeros enteros.

Comment: Más allá que podría escribirse de una forma más concisa, no veo nada malo en tu código. ¿Qué error tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes solucionarlo convirtiendo el resultado final a `float` no es necesario convertir los valores a sumar puedes usar la funcion `CAST` o `CONVERT`

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
 CONVERT(FLOAT,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN tier = 't2' 
            THEN 
                total_calls
            ELSE 0.00 
        END
    )/ 
    SUM(total_calls)
 ) as Total
From #prueba_real
```

Comment: No entiendo como este código soluciona el problema original (error).

Answer (score 0):

Además de que el rendimiento se puede ver penalizado, porque tener que hacer una función sum de una columna por cada fila, no es lo más operativo, pero como no has puesto la query de origen, ni la tabla sobre la que trabajas.

**Dos** cosas a cambiar.

Para devolver un valor con decimales, debieras de convertir a un **tipo de dato**, que permita dos decimales. Si realizas un cast a float, no puedes controlar el número de decimales que retornará a la salida.

Otro posible error esta en que el **total de llamadas sea 0**, por tanto se produzca un 8134 Error de division entre cero. Tienes que prevenir, esta operación.

```
CREATE TABLE #Prueba_real (id int, tier varchar(2), total_Calls int)
INSERT INTO #Prueba_real (id, tier, total_Calls)
VALUES
(1,'t2',0),
(2,'t1',0),
(3,'t1',0),
(4,'t2',0),
(5,'t2',0);

Select
CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN tier = 't2' 
            THEN CAST(total_calls AS FLOAT) 
            ELSE 0.00 
        END) 
AS FLOAT) 
/CASE WHEN (SUM(CAST(total_calls AS FLOAT))) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE  
(SUM(CAST(total_calls AS FLOAT)))  END
AS decimal (10,2))
From 
#PRUEBA_REAL ;
```

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 0):

La consulta la veo bien y le genere datos de prueba y me retorna valores con decimales. pero debe tener encuenta que sql server convierte la informacion deacuerdo a los formatos de entrada y salida de la operacion muchas veces realiza conversion implicita(automaticamente).

en el siguiente ejemplo puede ver que teniendo 4 variables (2 float y 2 decimales) se pueden realizar operaciones matematicas entre ella y dependiendo de los tipos de valores de entrada o de salida sql server se ajusta automaticamente.

mira que en cada uno de los ejemplo el valor puede cambiar deacuerdo a la definicion del datos de entrada o de salida y la prioridad siempre la va tener el tipo Int

```
declare @Float1 as float=3
declare @Float2 as float=5
declare @Int1 as Int=3
declare @Int2 as Int=5
----------------------------
declare @resultInt1 as Int=0
declare @resultFloat1 as float=0
declare @resultInt2 as Int=0
declare @resultFloat2 as float=0
declare @resultInt3 as Int=0
declare @resultFloat3 as float=0
declare @resultInt4 as Int=0
declare @resultFloat4 as float=0
declare @resultFloat5 as float=0

set @resultInt1=@Int2/@Int1
set @resultFloat1=@Int2/@Int1
set @resultInt2=@Int2/@Float1
set @resultFloat2=@Int2/@Float1
set @resultInt3=@Float2/@Int1
set @resultFloat3=@Float2/@Int1
set @resultInt4=@Float2/@Float1
set @resultFloat4=@Int2/@Int1
set @resultFloat4=@Int2/@Int1
set @resultFloat5=Cast(@Int2 as float)/Cast(@Int1 as float)
```

El resultado es 
resultInt1   **=1**

resultFloat1 **=1**

resultInt2   **=1**

resultFloat2     **=1.6666666666666667**

resultInt3   **=1.6666666666666667**

resultFloat3     **=1**

resultInt4   **=1.6666666666666667**

resultFloat5  **=1**

[Ejemplo con varios casos](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/077db/7)

espero que te sirva el ejemplo